# How to create Application Variable in Node Js Application

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I got a requirement and in that requirement, I have to use a variable that has the same value for all running process and if I change form a process then it should be reflected in all process. I have the idea in java we have an application variable.

In Node js, I used only Heroku variable and I do not have experience of other node variables so if anyone having any idea please suggest me because we cannot update Heroku variable, These variable work as constant.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean? are you wanting a constant variable over multiple heroku apps?

Comment: and in node js, you can have a server-wide variable which any "process" can access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got an answer after doing lots of R&D. We can create a property in `process object`. Process a predefined object in the node server.

```
process.env.variable_name = 'Value';
```

You can access this value in any process and update in any process. Value for this process always the same for all process.

```
console.log(process.env.variable_name);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using something like Redis to share data between processes, there is a great node module for this: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis. You can also share data between processes that are not even authored in Node.js.

Also the data can be stored to non-volatile storage, meaning you don't lose it if the processes recycle.

Data can also be shared across machines if necessary using one Redis db.

e.g.

```
var redis = require("redis");

var redisConfig = { 
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
};
var redisClient = redis.createClient(redisConfig);

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.set("key", "value");

client.get("key", function(err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
});
```